# box-shadow style not applied to radio buttons in Mozilla

Tags: html, css, radio-button, mozilla

I have made a radio button control which works perfectly in Chrome, yet it's not working in Mozilla.

The HTML:

```
<input type='radio' class="myRadio" name='a' checked/><span> A</span>
<br>
<input type='radio'  class="myRadio" name='a'/><span> B</span>
<br>
<input type='radio'  class="myRadio" name='a'/> <span> C</span>
```

The CSS:

```
input[type='radio'].myRadio {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid darkgray;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    padding:0px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px gray inset;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px gray inset;
}
input[type='radio'].myRadio:hover {
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px orange inset;
     -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px orange inset;
}
input[type='radio'].myRadio:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 20% auto;    
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-top:0px;

}
input[type='radio'].myRadio:checked:before {
    background:orange;
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmu8H/143/)

Comment: Do you mean [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Comment: Have you permitted permitted_uri_chars in config file ?

Comment: pls provide relevant info to us

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-moz-appearance: none;
```

Apparently you need to turn off default appearance setting to make `box-shadow` (no prefix required) work.

If you examine the user agent style rules (turn on “Show Browser Styles” under "Inspector" in the options (gear) panel), you see

```
border: 2px inset #F0F0F0 !important;
```

The `!important` here is forcing this style to take precedence over yours, I suppose in an attempt to enforce "native" appearance of radio buttons. You may find some clues in this old ticket: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605985.

Comment: Can u please currect my CSS as i did not get it yet.

Comment: Background color is not getting added here